# Stuck thread when tomcat stops

Tags: java, spring, mariadb

When my Java Spring webapp stops it takes a lot of time, and in the catalina outputs I have found there is a blocked therad and its name is "**pool-(x)-thread-(y)**".

```
[ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pool-5-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried to debug the application and I have found the same thread:

[image]

If I try to suspend that thread, the trace is not very useful:

[image]

It can be anything... but I tought about 3 things:

- aysnc process
- schedulation
- database pool

I have excluded the first two because I tried to rename the thread in the pool and the name doesn't match the blocked one.
The last option is the database. The application uses mariadb-java-client-2.3.0 library stored in /WEB-INF/lib folder of the application.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: During shutdown take stacktrace dump of all threads. Then check the one that you get report (in log) of being blocked and check what exactly it executes. To take stacktraces you can use `jstack` tool (in JDK) or `jcmd` (also available in JDK)

Comment: It's a single threaded executor by the looks of it, how is that related to database?

Comment: The point is that the thread is already stucked when tomcat is shutdowned, the stack is unuseful (usafe park)

Comment: @Kayaman maybe I'm wrong it is not related to the database.

Comment: It's a thread in a threadpool, waiting for tasks (it's blocked on `take()`). Don't just assume this is what your problem is.

Comment: Or are you saying Tomcat is telling you the "webapp appears to have started a thread named xxx but has failed to stop it"? In any case, make sure to release any resources you've acquired.

Comment: @Kayaman I added the catalina log, tomcat cannot stop that thread. But I don't know who opened that threadpool

Comment: Disable parts of your application and see at what point in the shutdown the message no longer shows up. Then you'll know who's to blame.